# Smooth transition effects using Qt

Tags: qt, window

How to implement **smooth transition** effects while opening one Window from another using QT.

By **smooth transition**,  I meant effects like we see in Iphones/Windows Metros etc.

Please suggest some libraries or how to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [QPropertyAnimation](http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qpropertyanimation.html) Class and try animating opacity, size etc.